# Is there a way to join all arrays in clickhouse column and then filter for duplicates?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a clickhouse table with one of it columns being Array(T).
When I run 
`SELECT array_field FROM my_table`
I get the following:

```
1 | {a, b, c}
--------------
2 | {a, b}
--------------
3 | {d, e}
```

I need to find a way to get a list of unique values in all of that lists, just like that:

```
{a, b, c, d, e}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the same in array in one row: use `groupUniqArray` with `-Array` combinator. Check [docs](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/combinators/#array)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table 

┌─array_field───┐
│ ['a','b','c'] │
│ ['a','b']     │
│ ['d','e']     │
└───────────────┘

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec. 

SELECT DISTINCT arrayJoin(array_field)
FROM my_table 

┌─arrayJoin(array_field)─┐
│ a                      │
│ b                      │
│ c                      │
│ d                      │
│ e                      │
└────────────────────────┘

SELECT groupUniqArrayArray(array_field)
FROM my_table 

┌─groupUniqArrayArray(array_field)─┐
│ ['c','e','d','a','b']            │
└──────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution to your problem

```
SELECT arrayDistinct(arrayFlatten(groupArray(array_field)))
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solutions that works for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT arrayJoin(array_field)
FROM my_table
```